# Laravel Eloquent Foreign Key Relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have question about Laravel Eloquent. I created few tables and models, ~like this:

**Trip**

- id
- name
- user

**User**

- id
- email

**Message**

- id
- content
- trip
- user

How can I get all message for single user with all foreign keys? You know, all data from this tables. Like this:

```
[
    1 => [
        'content',
        'trip' => [
            'name'
        ],
        'user' => [
            'email'
        ]
    ]
]
```

It's possible, to get in easy way all data?

My models:

```
// Message.php:

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function trip()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Trip');
}

// Trip.php:

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

// User.php:

public function trips()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Trip');
}

public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Message');
}
```

**My Code**

```
dd(
    User::with([
        'sent',
        'recipient'
    ])->find(2)->toArray()
);
```

And what I want to get:

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bADYK.png)

Comment: As you asked to check your updated question with screenshot, you didn't mention about your `sent` and `recipient` relations in your `User` model. Please update your `User` model with `sent` and `recipient` relations.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the load method.

Lets say you have a user

```
$user->load('messages'); // var_dump($user);
```

If you vardump your user object you will see the related messages were loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Use eager loading to achieve that.
Try this:

```
$users = User::with([
        'messages.trip',
    ])->get();

dd($users);
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading